# How do i change label in another form with backgroundworker process c#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have 2 form (formA & formB) in my project c#, i want to run some process in backgroundworker when i click a button in formA.

can i update from backgroundworker to label in formB?
here's the code in formA

```
        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Stimulus stimulus = new Stimulus();
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        stimulus.Show();
        stimulus.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { stimulus.perbaharuiStimulus("+"); });
        watch.Start();
        do
        {

        } while (watch.Elapsed.Seconds != 2);
        watch.Restart();
        stimulus.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { stimulus.perbaharuiStimulus("MAJU"); });
        do
        {

        } while (watch.Elapsed.Seconds != 6);
        watch.Restart();
        stimulus.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { stimulus.perbaharuiStimulus(""); });
        do
        {

        } while (watch.Elapsed.Seconds != 2);
        watch.Stop();
        stimulus.Close();
    }
```

and heres code in formB

```
        public Stimulus()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    }
    public void perbaharuiStimulus(string stimulus)
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            lbStimulus.Text = stimulus;
        });
    }
```

thankyou for attention..

Comment: The background worker need an instance of the second form.  See my two form project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your code like below and it'll work fine.

1. Change perbaharuiStimulus code to

   ```
   lbStimulus.Text = stimulus;
   ```
2. Change `WorkerReportsProgress` to `True`
3. Change `backgroundWorker1_DoWork` to below

   ```
       Stimulus stimulus = new Stimulus();
       Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
       backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(1, stimulus);
       watch.Start();
       do
       {

       } while (watch.Elapsed.Seconds != 2);

       watch.Restart();
       backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(2, stimulus);
       do
       {

       } while (watch.Elapsed.Seconds != 6);

       watch.Restart();
       backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(3, stimulus);
       do
       {

       } while (watch.Elapsed.Seconds != 2);
       watch.Stop();

       stimulus.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { stimulus.Close(); });
   ```
4. Add the `backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged` event and put below code in it

   ```
   private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       Stimulus stimulus = ( Stimulus)e.UserState;
       if(e.ProgressPercentage==1)
           stimulus.perbaharuiStimulus("+");
       if (e.ProgressPercentage == 2)
           stimulus.perbaharuiStimulus("MAJU");
       if (e.ProgressPercentage == 3)
           stimulus.perbaharuiStimulus("");

       stimulus.Show();
   }
   ```

I hope this help you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You've written a nice answer, however you really shouldn't instantiate the `Stimulus` form in the background worker as doing so ties it to the background thread rather than the UI thread. You want to instantiate the form either before `DoWork` or in an `Invoke()` call inside it. Otherwise good work!

Answer (score 0):

You can update a label in any form from a background worker using `Invoke(...)` like you did it. (Assuming stimulus is a field). 
It is enough to call Invoke once. `Stimulus.Invoke` executes the delegate on the control thread of the stimulus form. So you can decide, whee you dispatch the thread. I'd recommend to do this in `perbarauiStimulus`, since that would reduce the chance that someone forgets to dispatch the call.

But there is one potential issues with your code:

Don't use exact comparison for elapsed time. Prefer using '>='. Since you are dealing with seconds this will rarely be an actual problem, but it may result in an infinite loop.

If `stimulus` isn't a field you have to create an instance of `Stimulus` **outside** of the background worker, because if you create it inside the worker Method, the form will run its message loop on the background workers thread. This eliminates the use of a background worker since the operation runs now synchronously from sytimulus view.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be creating the form in the background thread. Doing so will assign the form to *that* thread instead of the UI thread, meaning the form is now on a different thread than the message pump.

What you can do to fix this is to invoke the instantiation and viewing of the form on the UI thread, then your following `Invoke` calls should work.

```
Stimulus stimulus;

this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
{
    stimulus = new Stimulus();
    stimulus.Show();
});

//No need to invoke this since perbaharuiStimulus() calls Invoke() as well.
stimulus.perbaharuiStimulus("+");

//The rest of your code...
```

Apart from that you're doing everything correctly.